# Set the last modified date in the CompactFramework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime(v=vs.80).aspx) provides details for a function to set the date and time that a file was last written to, but it is not available in the CompactFramework. There did not appear to be a [PInvoke option](http://pinvoke.net/) for this method. Is there a good alternative in the Compact Framework (currently targetting .NET v2.0)?

I'm looking to create an empty file on disk and update it about every minute. If power is removed, the last modified date of the file will be used to create a "Power off" event (accurate to minute, of course).

Comment: Ooh, tried a different Google search and this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673921/change-file-lastwritedate-in-compact-framework) might have the answer I need...just checking.

Comment: This question is answered by two separate questions (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673921/change-file-lastwritedate-in-compact-framework and (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329930/how-to-p-invoke-setfiletime-with-null-parameters. Will leave this comment for a few days and then delete this question.