# Change file creation time on compact framework

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I need to set file creation time after I download it using sockets. In CF FileInfo.CreationTime is readonly. I tried to use P/Invoke solution from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673921/change-file-lastwritedate-in-compact-framework), but it won't work: I get error 6 (Invalid handle).

According to MSDN first parameter for SetFileTime() must be a handle, while in the topic mentioned it is string, and somebody says that it works for him. What am I doing wrong? If I need to use handle, how can I get this handle in CF and how should I change SetFileTime() declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.  The answer you point to is obviously wrong, though it was accepted.

At any rate, you need to pass in a HANDLE (IntPtr or however you'd like to represent it) that is returned from a call to CreateFile - which [you'll also need to P/Invoke](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.CreateFile).

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")] 
private static extern bool SetFileTime(IntPtr fileHandle, 
                                  ref long creationTime, 
                                  ref long lastAccessTime, 
                                  ref long lastWriteTime);
```

Be sure to call [CloseHandle](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll.CloseHandle) when you're done.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment about the linked answer being incorrect - the answer to the linked question is also by you. Was there a different answer accepted before?

Comment: I don't think so.  Just looking at these now, the other answer is definitely wrong.  The API takes in a HANDLE as the first parameter, not a string path.  The answer here is correct, the other one (even though I posted it) is wrong.